# Where to add the connection string in the ASP.NET 5 app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I created a new **ASP.NET 5 Web API** app and installed **Microsoft.AspNet.OData** and **Entity Framework 6.1.3**. I created a controller from **ODataController**.

My question is, where should I add the connection string for Entity Framework? As I understand, the **ASP.NET 5 Web API** apps doesn't have web.config.

Comment: First you create your .edmx file so app.config file created it self.

Comment: @kaushik-maheta ASP.NET 5 no longer has a web.config (and never had an app.config).